# How can we possibly query documents but not send sensitive information to the client?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to query my user document, in Cloud Firestore, based on users location and users date of birth. The location is stored as a Geofire coordinate.

I want to be able to retrieve the user document but the date of birth and location should only be used as query conditions and not to return them to the client-side. It looks like it is impossible not to send the information back to the client. Even with subcollections, I would need to do it in two separate transaction meaning that I would be returning the document containing the sensitive information anyways.

Is it even possible to securely query Firestore without exposing the sensitive information?

Here's what I want to acheive:

I have a user collection laid out like that:

```
name: string
dob: date
location: {
    geohash: string
    geopoint: [double, double]
}
```

On the client side I only want to expose the `name:` of the user **only** but people should be able to filter user names by `dob:` and by `location:`. Is it doable?

Comment: You should try using [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: That won't help because security rules are not filters. This means that I will just stop the 
 other users from accessing the document, making it impossible to query.

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated my description. Maybe it will be clearer like this.

Comment: How about an HTTPS callable function that does the query and does whatever suppression  you want before sending the result?

Comment: @danh That would work however I would have to manage offline data persistence myself in that case. I am looking to stick with the Firestore solution in terms of communicating data back to the client.

Comment: Is the idea that it's okay for user to know that somebody's dob is in a range, but not okay for them to know the exact dob?  (same question for location?).  If firestore had the spot-on solution  for this -- like an extra query param to filter out certain document keys in the result -- wouldn't I still be able to work out a person's dob or location with a series of increasingly narrow queries?

Comment: That challenge gives me an idea: how about, whatever resolution you're okay with the client seeing, store only that resolution in the public data?  Eg. a birth year.  The public data can have a ref to higher res data elsewhere under the cover of tighter rules

Comment: @danh That is a good point. I already thought of it. The way the DOB filter is set up on the client is as an age range meaning if I am looking to find someone that is between 20 and 22 years old, the query would look for users born between date.now() - 20 years old and date.now() - 22 years. For the location the filter uses a range value meaning that I only want to know if the person is within a certain range

Comment: Although possible to triangulate someone's location, the geohash has to be less accurate in order to avoid precise localization. That is no longer an issue with the database, so it would be out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't filter the data in a document if you directly read it from client.

There are at least two solutions:

1. Separately store your users' sensitive and insensitive information in two documents.
2. Use Firebase Cloud Function to add a new layer between your client and database. So the cloud function can read and filter the data in user document and send it back to the client. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for a way of doing it natively in Firestore in order to utilize the offline data persistence. Sadly the way Firestore is set up, it is impossible to query a document without returning it's content to the client.

Comment: The generally accepted workaround for this is to have two separate collections (one private, one public) to handle this use case.  This could be a subcollection or a root collection.  A user's credit card would be in the private collection, but a user's name and user name would be in the public.

Comment: @Jonathan I understand that solution however this is also an issue and I will be reusing your example to try to explain to you the issue here. 

Let's say that you store the credit card number and the credit card type (Visa, Mastercard, etc.) in that subcollection. I want to query all the users that have a mastercard but not send the credit card number back to the client. Wouldn't that be impossible using this method?

Comment: Yes, but you still need the same data model.  You disable access to the credit card collection in firebase rules, and create a firebase callable function to get what you want.  Either way, only an admin should access this, so the function should check for admin privileges.

Comment: @Jonathan I can see your case and that make sense for you example. Back to my example, let's say that we are a dating app and I need to know the age and location of each user in order to display the right person to each other BUT I don't want to send the location or the date of birth back to the client. However, I don't need to be an admin to access that information. I simply want to query against it and return the right user based on filters that the other users have set.

Comment: Again, the concept is still the same. You have the name and age in a public users collection, and dob and location in another collection private with Firestone rules. Use a callable firebase function to query the data you want and only return the keys you want. You have all privileges in a function, or you can check logged in user. Impossible to search something client only without showing all values.

Comment: @Jonathan You are right. This seems to be the only way of achieving my purpose. Thank you.